# Self writen MaskedInput caused infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I wrote a number input with thousand separator, everything is so smooth util I press a number than press backspace and press a number again (do it fast), it causes an infinite loop where my input value keep changing.
Please have a look and let me know where is the failure in my logic.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const addSeparator = (input, divider) => {
  return Number(input.toString())
    .toFixed(0)
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, `$1${divider || '.'}`);
};

const removeNonDigits = (value) => {
  const formatedValue = !value && value !== 0 ? '' : value.toString();
  return formatedValue.replace(/\D/g, '');
};

const MaskedNumberInput = (
  { onChangeText, value, maxValue, ...props },
  ref,
) => {
  const [maskedValue, setMaskedValue] = React.useState(
    value === '' ? value : addSeparator(value),
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onMaskedInputChangeText(value);
  }, [value]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (onChangeText) {
      onChangeText(removeNonDigits(maskedValue));
    }
  }, [maskedValue]);

  const onMaskedInputChangeText = (newValue) => {
    let digitValue = removeNonDigits(newValue);

    if (
      maxValue !== '' &&
      maxValue !== null &&
      maxValue !== undefined &&
      digitValue > maxValue
    ) {
      digitValue = maxValue;
    }

    if (removeNonDigits(maskedValue) === digitValue) {
      console.tron.log('return');
      return;
    }
    const maskedDigitValue =
      digitValue === '' ? digitValue : addSeparator(digitValue);
    setMaskedValue(maskedDigitValue);
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={ref}
      value={maskedValue}
      onChangeText={onMaskedInputChangeText}
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```